# how to get daterangefilter working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have created a daterangefilter:

```
app.filter('dateRangefilter', function() {
  return function(input,dateFrom,dateTo) {
    return _.filter(input, function (d) {
      return Date.parse(d.date) >= Date.parse(dateFrom) && Date.parse(d.date) <= Date.parse(dateTo);
    });
  }
});
```

However when I try to filter my list I get an error:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data | dateRange(dateFrom,dateTo) ">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the data:

```
$scope.data = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "een", 
      "date":"12/08/2015"
    }, {
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "twee",  
      "date":"11/08/2015"
    }];
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/km23JzP925y95bVCPkqA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your line:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | dateRange(dateFrom,dateTo) ">
        {{item.name}}
</li>
```

to:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:dateRange(dateFrom,dateTo) ">
            {{item.name}}
</li>
```

With this your code works but I don't know if it has to do whatever you want.

Regards.